# Is the phrase "a sense of feeling" correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases, phrasal-verbs

For example if you say:

> Do you have a **sense** of feeling that you are better than everyone?

Is the above sentence correct? if yes, what does the word sense mean in this context?

Thank you!

Comment: In general, you can have a sense (of something being the case) or you can have a feeling (of something being the case). You would not combine the words like that.

Comment: I disagree with the question being closed as off-topic. I'm sorry you got shut down like that @Dinu G. Mod: op was asking if a given syntax made sense or not _and why_. This harkens to the sheer volume of idioms and colloquialisms, errant exceptions and broken "rules" English is laden with. I'd be delighted to see the dictionary that could have provided both an answer and it's explanation.

Answer (score 6):

"Do you feel that you are better than everyone?" would be a better usage.
"Do you have a sense that you are better than everyone?" would also be acceptable, though, idiomatically, most English speakers would be less likely to use it.

"Do you have a sense of feeling that you are better than everyone?" is similar to saying, "do you think you have the thought you are better than everyone?" It's both redundant and mixes tense.

Comment: This makes so much sense and that's why I was confused when I heard someone say that. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

> sense of feeling

feeling is a sense, so you don't have to repeat that. It comes in as tautology, a *needless repetition of an idea, statement, or word*. See [Marriam Webster, tautology, bullet point 1.b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tautology).

just use:

- Do you feel that you are better than everyone?

or eventually

- Do you sense that you are better than everyone?

Comment: Exactly! Feeling is a sense and that's why I was confused when I heard someone say that. Thank you so much for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Many English speakers would understand the meaning but it is not a common construct. Common usage would include "sense" or "feeling" but not both.